# Securely copying files between two remote servers

Tags: linux, ssh, mac, scp

I am trying to copy (scp) files from one remote server to another remote server. The remote servers are running Ubuntu and are using SSH authentication. The servers synchronise with LDAP, and all users public keys are stored on the LDAP server.

I am running a Mac with OSX Mavericks - I followed these instructions to set up agent forwarding on my Mac: https://developer.github.com/guides/using-ssh-agent-forwarding/

When I try and run the command:

```
luca-macbook:~ luca$ scp users@remoteserver:/home/ubuntu/file users@remoteserver:/home/ubuntu/
```

I get the following error:

```
Host key verification failed.
lost connection
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Secondly, if I want to copy a whole directory over, do I just type the same as above and it will move all the files in the directory to or do I need to have a -R somewhere?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

That error means that the remote host's key has changed or you are using `StrictHostKeyChecking`:

> ```
> StrictHostKeyChecking
>    If this flag is set to “yes”, ssh(1) will never automatically add host keys to the
>    ~/.ssh/known_hosts file, and refuses to connect to hosts whose host key has changed.
>    This provides maximum protection
>    against trojan horse attacks, though it can be annoying when the /etc/ssh
>    /ssh_known_hosts file is poorly maintained or when connections to new hosts are
>    frequently made.  This option forces the user to manually add all new hosts.  
>    If this flag is set to “no”, ssh will automatically add new host keys to the user
>    known hosts files.  If this flag is set to “ask”, new host keys will be added to the
>    user known host files only after the user has confirmed that is what they really want
>    to do, and ssh will refuse to connect to hosts whose host key has changed.  The host
>    keys of known hosts will be verified automatically in all cases.  The argument must 
>    be “yes”, “no”, or “ask”.  The default is “ask”.
> ```

Purge it using:

```
$ ssh-keygen -R $remoteserver
```

and try again. This time, you should be asked to confirm the identity of the remote server via its key fingerprint.

To transfer whole directories, the `-r` is used:

> ```
> -r      Recursively copy entire directories.  Note that scp follows symbolic links
>         encountered in the tree traversal.
> ```

This is all documented in the [`scp(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp), [`ssh-keygen(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keygen) and [`ssh_config(5)`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) manpages.

Comment: StrictHostKeyChecking is set to 'ask'. What do you mean by the remote host's key has changed? They don't change as far as I know..

Comment: You can change them whenever you want using `ssh-keygen -A` as `root`. You can to retrieve the fingerprint of the remote host with `ssh-keyscan` and compare it with the one in your local database (`~/.ssh/known_hosts`).